# Emberjs - Unable to render a nested view by using appendTo and {{render}} helpers

Tags: ember.js

I am trying a simple event handling mechanism in nested views scenario by using appendTo method & `{{render}}` helper and is throwing 'Cannot call method lookup of null' error while loading

JSFiddle for the same - [Simple nested view event handling](http://jsfiddle.net/anshulguleria/vQpe6/)

One more observation is it all works fine if I write `{{render 'parent'}}` in the application template and remove the creation of parent from java script, any ideas??

Answer (score 4):

How to fix:

There does not appear to be anything wrong with your views or templates. They will work if you use the Ember router to manage your views instead of creating them manually via appendTo. So instead of:

```
var view = App.ParentView.create({ controller: App.ParentController.create() });
view.appendTo('#dvViewRender');
```

use the router:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("parent", { path: "/" });
});
```

and define an application template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">{{outlet}}</script>
```

> Prove it!

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mgrassotti/vQpe6/1/

> Why does that work?

The `render` helper was designed to be used within the context of an Ember.Router managed view. When you call `{{render "child"}}` ember tries to find an appropriate controller class for the child template.

> What if I really want to use the appendTo method?

ok, but can't use the `render` helper. Other options:

- `{{partial 'child'}}` will insert the child template but will not connect it to ChildView or ChildController
- use the view helper, which will insert App.ChildView and it's render it's template in the context of ParentController
- use an outlet, then manually connect it to App.ChildView with an instance of App.ChildController

*** UPDATE (BASED ON COMMENT) ***

> Due to this dynamic and independent nature I can't embed the whole page layout and the widgets in one application template So any suggestions for using Ember in this kind of scenarios??

Each widget can be a separate ember application. Each will still have a router to manage it's state but by setting `history: none` that router will not be connected to the browser's url. For example:

```
var Widget2App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#widget2',
  history: 'none',
  ApplicationView: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'widget2',
  }),
  ParentView: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'parent2',
```

Updated example showing 2 ember applications in one page: http://jsfiddle.net/mgrassotti/L6aVB/

Comment: thanks for the quick reply and the reasons for not using router are
1. My application is not a single page application and it is an ASP.NET MVC app which has its own routing mechanism
2. My application has kind of widgetized UI just like [iGoogle.com](http://www.google.com/ig) where widgets work independently with out the knowledge of others and can be add, delete, re-position dynamically. Due to this dynamic and independent nature I can't embed the whole page layout and the widgets in one application template
So any suggestions for using Ember in this kind of scenarios??

Comment: No problem. You can still use the router, just set `history: none` so that widgets route don't impact your overall application. Updated my answer with an example..

Comment: this perfectly suits my scenario and I have a small concern, is it OK to have multiple application instances and will be there any side effects / impacts which need to taken care while using this approach?

Comment: is there any provision in Ember to perform remove, reload and rerender operations on whole Ember application as these are the very important actions required for any widgetized UI.

Comment: It's normally used for testing, but you could probably use App#reset to perform remove/reload/re-render operations on an entire app. See: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_reset

Comment: For sure it is OK to have multiple app instances. A typical Ember app will interact with objects in it's own namespace and should not be aware of or impacted by other applications. Things to look out for are any situations where your application code is interacting with globals For example, `$jQuery` is global so in your views always use `this.$`. If you are doing a lot of work with widgets check out the oasis project, it's designed specifically for this use case: http://oasisjs.com/